# Does Function Composition rely on Partial Application?

Tags: f#, functional-programming

Does Function Composition rely on Partial Application?

### Here's my understanding:

Observe the following functions that have some duplication of function calls:

```
let updateCells (grid:Map<(int * int), Cell>) =

    grid |> Map.toSeq
         |> Seq.map snd
         |> Seq.fold (fun grid c -> grid |> setReaction (c.X, c.Y)) grid

let mutable _cells = ObservableCollection<Cell>( grid |> Map.toSeq
                                                      |> Seq.map snd
                                                      |> Seq.toList )
let cycleHandler _ = 

    self.Cells <- ObservableCollection<Cell>( grid |> cycleThroughCells
                                                   |> Map.toSeq
                                                   |> Seq.map snd
                                                   |> Seq.toList )
```

If you’ve noticed, the following code appears in all three functions:

```
grid |> Map.toSeq
     |> Seq.map snd
```

**Function Composition**

Within functional programming, we can fuse functions together so that they can become one function.

To do this, let’s create a new function from the duplicated sequence of functions:

```
let getCells = Map.toSeq >> Seq.map snd >> Seq.toList
```

Now if you’re attentive, you will have noticed that we don’t use any arguments when using Function Composition. Hence, the grid value is not used. The reason behind this is because of Partial Application.

**Partial Application**

I’m still learning all these functional programming techniques. However, my understanding is that partial application is a technique within functional programming that postpones the need to accept a complete set of arguments for a given function. In other words, partial application is the act of deferring the acceptance of a complete set of arguments for a given function in which there is an expectation that the end-client will provide the rest of the arguments later. At least, that’s my understanding.

**We can now take a function like:**

```
let updateCells (grid:Map<(int * int), Cell>) =

    grid |> Map.toSeq
         |> Seq.map snd
         |> Seq.fold (fun grid c -> grid |> setReaction (c.X, c.Y)) grid
```

**And refactor it to something like:**

```
let updateCells (grid:Map<(int * int), Cell>) =

    grid |> getCells
         |> Seq.fold (fun grid c -> grid |> setReaction (c.X, c.Y)) grid
```

Are my thoughts regarding Function Composition being coupled with Partial Application accurate?

Comment: Your thoughts are accurate. I wouldn't say function composition relies on partial application but works with it. I tend to think of the supplied arguments as being on the stack and the when the function needs them if they are not defined as arguments, it takes them off of the stack.

Comment: Yea, but I tried providing arguments inside the composition definition and it just wouldn't compile. idk...

Comment: What exactly did you try to do that didn't compile?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Generics

Actually, if you take the expression

```
let getCells = Map.toSeq >> Seq.map snd >> Seq.toList
```

and attempt to compile it as a stand-alone expression, you'll get a compiler error:

> error FS0030: Value restriction. The value 'getCells' has been inferred to have generic type
>       val getCells : (Map<'_a,'_b> -> '_b list) when '_a : comparison
>   Either make the arguments to 'getCells' explicit or, if you do not intend for it to be generic, add a type annotation.

The reason it works in your case is because you're *using* the `getCells` function with `grid`, which means that the compiler infers it to have a constrained type.

In order to keep it generic, you can rephrase it using an explicit argument:

```
let getCells xs = xs |> Map.toSeq |> Seq.map snd |> Seq.toList
```

This expression is a valid stand-alone expression of the type `Map<'a,'b> -> 'b list when 'a : comparison`.

## Point-free

The style used with the `>>` function composition operator is called [point-free](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacit_programming). It works well with partial application, but isn't quite the same.

## Application

There is, however, an example of partial function application in this example:

```
let getCells xs = xs |> Map.toSeq |> Seq.map snd |> Seq.toList
```

The function `snd` has the following type:

```
'a * 'b -> 'b
```

It's function that takes a single argument.

You could also write the above `getCells` function *without* partial application of the `snd` function:

```
let getCells xs = xs |> Map.toSeq |> Seq.map (fun x -> snd x) |> Seq.toList
```

Notice that instead of a partially applied function passed to `Seq.map`, you can pass a lambda expression. The `getCells` function is still a function composed from other functions, but it no longer relies on partial application of `snd`.

Thus, to partially (pun intended) answer your question: **function composition doesn't have to rely on partial function composition.**

## Currying

In F#, functions are *curried* by default. This means that all functions take exactly *one* argument, and returns a value. Sometimes (often), the return value is another function.

Consider, as an example, the `Seq.map` function. If you call it with *one* argument, the return value is *another* function:

```
Seq.map snd
```

This expression has the type `seq<'a * 'b> -> seq<'b>`, because the return value of `Seq.map snd` is another function.

## Eta reduction

This means that you can perform an *Eta reduction* on the above lambda expression `fun x -> snd x`, because `x` appears on both sides of the expression. The result is simply `snd`, and the entire expression becomes

```
let getCells xs = xs |> Map.toSeq |> Seq.map snd |> Seq.toList
```

As you can see, partial application isn't *necessary* for function composition, but it does **make it much easier**.

## Impartial

The above composition using the pipe operator (`|>`) still relies on partial application of the functions `Map.toSeq`, `Seq.map`, etcetera. In order to demonstrate that composition doesn't rely on partial application, here's an 'impartial' (the opposite of partial? (pun)) alternative:

```
let getCells xs =
    xs
    |> (fun xs' -> Map.toSeq xs')
    |> (fun xs' -> Seq.map (fun x -> snd x) xs')
    |> (fun xs' -> Seq.toList xs')
```

Notice that this version makes extensive use of lambda expressions instead of partial application.

I wouldn't compose functions in this way; I only included this alternative to demonstrate that it can be done.

Comment: Why would you not compose functions this way?  Would there be a use case for it?  Such as building this on-the-fly from live user input?

Comment: I ask because of an article, "[Why Concatenative Programming Matters](http://evincarofautumn.blogspot.com/2012/02/why-concatenative-programming-matters.html)", which states that "In concatenative languages, composition is implicit. However, this does not mean that function application becomes explicit—it actually becomes unnecessary. And as it turns out, this peculiar fact makes these languages a whole lot simpler to build, use, and reason about." Perhaps also simpler because Application uses variables, lambdas, & applications, but Composition uses just functions & compositions.

Comment: @MicroservicesOnDDD I wouldn't use explicit lambda expressions like that because they aren't necessary.

Answer (score 9):

Composition depends on *first-class functions*, not really on partial applications.

What is required to implement composition is that:

- Functions must be able to be taken as arguments and returned as return values
- Function signatures must be valid types (if you want the composition to be strongly-typed)

Partial application creates more *opportunities* for composition, but in principle you can easily define function composition without it.

For example, C# doesn't have partial application*, but you can still compose two functions together, as long as the signatures match:

```c#
Func<a, c> Compose<a, b, c>(this Func<a, b> f, 
                            Func<b, c> g) 
{
    return x => g(f(x));
}
```

which is just `>>` with an uglier syntax: `f.Compose(g)`.

However, there is one interesting connection between composition and partial application. The definition of the `>>` operator is:

```
let (>>) f g x = g(f(x))
```

and so, when you write `foo >> bar`, you are indeed *partially applying* the `(>>)` function, ie omitting the `x` argument to get the `fun x = g(f(x))` partial result.

But, as I said above, this isn't strictly necessary. The `Compose` function above is equivalent to F#'s `>>` operator and doesn't involve any partial application; lambdas perform the same role in a slightly more verbose way.

---

* Unless you manually implement it, which nobody does. I.e. instead of writing

```c#
string foo(int a, int b) 
{ 
    return (a + b).ToString(); 
}
```

you'd have to write

```c#
Func<int, string> foo(int a) 
{ 
    return b => (a + b).ToString(); 
}
```

and then you'd be able to pass each argument separately just like in F#.